Deploying Go app with Docker Compose: dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: connection refused
I'm trying to deploy a Golang app using Docker Compose but unfortunately the PostgreSQL DB connection isn't working, and I really don't know why.
Here's my docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:16.3-alpine
    container_name: "backend-db"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - fullstack
    volumes:
      - database_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${DB_USERNAME}"]
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5
    expose:
      - "5432"

  api:
    build: .
    container_name: "backend-api"
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - fullstack

volumes:
  database_postgres:
  migrations:
networks:
  fullstack:
    driver: bridge

I'm doing a docker compose up --build to test the app locally and whenever my app tries to interact with the DB, I get:
dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: connection refused
However, if I change in the api networks: fullstack by - network_mode: "host" I get pq: SSL is not enabled on the server.
Please note that I'm using an .env file to load the environment variables, and in my case, the variable DB_DSN which is used in the Go code, has appended sslmode=disable but it looks like it's not being picked up:
postgres://myuser:mypassword@db/mydbname?sslmode=disable where db is the name of the database container in the docker compose file (is this correct?)

If you think the DB_DSN should be getting used with a host name db, but the error message is referring to [::1] (IPv6 "localhost"), then the database URL you show in the question doesn't seem to be used.  Do not disable Docker networking with network_mode: host!  What does the code look like that uses that variable?

The Variable DB_DSN is set nowhere in the definition of api. Environment variables are NOT automatically injected. Think of the .env file as an env file for the compose file, not your containers.
services:
  # snip
  api:
    build: .
    container_name: "backend-api"
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - DB_DSN=${DB_DSN}
    networks:
      - fullstack

You can also check via docker compose config how your docker compose is interpolated.
